# Update parents with count() of total children parent wise and country wise

Tags: mysql, sql

SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0830d)

```
"id"    "type"  "parent"    "country"   "totals"
1       3       0           US          0       //Desired output 5
2       10      1           US          0
3       10      1           US          0
4       10      1           US          0
5       10      1           US          0
6       10      1           US          0

7       3       0           US          0       //Desired output 5
8       10      7           US          0
9       10      7           US          0
10      10      7           US          0
11      10      7           US          0
12      10      7           US          0

13      3       0           SE          0       //Desired output 1
14      10      13          SE          0

15      3       0           SE          0       //Desired output 3
16      10      15          SE          0
17      10      15          SE          0
18      10      15          SE          0
```

In the above table, I'm trying to update all the parents with the count of their children `(how many children each has)`.

The parents are `type 3` and children are `type 10` and the country are at the side.

What I'm trying to do is:

```
`select count(*) as totalChildren ,parent,country where type= 10` then
`update table set totals = totalChildren where parent = parent from above and country = country from above`.
```

I've was doing something on these lines, but I seem to be going nowhere. Can you please help me?

```
UPDATE  likesd a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  country, parent, count(id) totalChildren
            FROM    likesd
            WHERE   type = 10
            GROUP   BY parent
        ) b ON a.country = b.country and a.parent=b.parent
SET     a.totals = b.totalChildren
WHERE   a.type = 3 and a.country = b.country;
```

**Edit - Working Answer**

```
UPDATE  likesd a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  country, parent, count(id) totalChildren
            FROM    likesd
            WHERE   type = 10
            GROUP   BY parent
        ) b ON a.id=b.parent and a.country = b.country
SET     a.totals = b.totalChildren
WHERE   a.type = 3 and a.id = b.parent and a.country = b.country;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. You had `a.parent = b.parent` where it should be `a.id = b.parent`.

```
UPDATE  likesd a
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT  parent, count(id) totalChildren
       FROM    likesd
      WHERE   type = 10
      GROUP   BY parent) b ON a.id=b.parent
SET     a.totals = b.totalChildren
WHERE   a.type = 3
```

(Sorry about the odd formatting.)

SQL fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c5b0d/1

Comment: That wont in MySql: `You can't specify target table 'parent' for update in FROM clause`. I did something similar to this earlier on, then found the above sql on this site.

Comment: you ignore that child is type 10 (although in the example there are only parent & child )

Comment: Well - in my previous example, yes. Since there is a parent reference, that should be sufficient unless we're working with corrupted data.

Comment: I updated my question with a fortified version of your answer. Do you see anything wrong with that? Sure it works, but I've put in the country and other `where` references, so it updates the right way.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it - you know if adding country is necessary. In other words - if there is ever a parent that has a child from a different country.